# How many times will postrotate run when defining logrotate for multiple directories?

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have the below configuration for rotating the DB backups. The `/var/mysql_backup/data/` contains two subdirectories `db1` and `db2`.

```
/var/mysql_backup/data/*/db.sql.gz {
    daily
    rotate 7
    nocompress
    notifempty
    missingok
    create 640 root root
    dateext
    dateformat _%Y_%m_%d_%s
    extension .sql.gz
    
    postrotate

        PATH=/var/mysql_backup/data/
        MYSQL_USER=USER
        MYSQL_PASS='PASS'
        MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
        MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS=" --single-transaction --quick"

        #Backup for db1
        mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} db1  > ${PATH}/db1/db.sql
        gzip -9f ${PATH}/db1/db.sql

        #Backup for db2
        mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} db2  > ${PATH}/db1/db.sql
        gzip -9f ${PATH}/db2/db.sql
    endscript
}
```

My question is: the `mysqldump` and `gzip` for each DB running once or twice? If they are running twice, then how to make them run once?

**Note**: I know that I can define configurations for db1 and db2 separately. But I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's run for every rotated file unless `sharedscripts` is set. Then it's only run once if at least one rotation occurs.
Don't overwrite the `PATH` variable! I added `nocreate`, `sharedscripts` and added a loop; the dump is created and compressed in one step.

```
/var/mysql_backup/data/*/db.sql.gz {
    daily
    rotate 7
    nocompress
    notifempty
    missingok
    create 640 root root
    dateext
    dateformat _%Y_%m_%d_%s
    extension .sql.gz
    nocreate
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        mysql_user=USER
        mysql_pass='PASS'

        for db in db1 db2; do
            mysqldump -u"$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_pass" --single-transaction --quick "$db" |
                gzip -9f > "/var/mysql_backup/data/$db/db.sql.gz"
        done
    endscript
}
```

Comment: thanks. It works perfectly